# What effect does the warp have?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In our game, we have entered an area that (not confirmed) has been affected by the warp. The main discrepancy is there are 3 different things, happening in different time frames; at the same time.

I'll explain:

- **Event 1:** There is an epic battle going on outside the entrance to the ship. Bodies decaying/decayed, but mainly Inquistorial Storm Troopers. This initial battle was to attempt to destroy the original crew on the ship. However, there is also Dark Eldar here, and (what looks like) a Space Marine, both which are out of place, but old, and decayed, like the rest of the bodies.
- **Event 2:** Further in to the ship, a pile of decayed bodies cover another Space Marine, but the Space Marine body is still (fairly) fresh. He appears to be part of the same squad as the Space Marine outside.
- **Event 3:** In the Chapel, presumably the place least affected by the warp, lay the remainder of the Squad the other Space Marines belong to, along with hordes of Dark Eldar, all of which are fairly fresh. No Storm Troopers to be seen.

So my question is: Can the Warp affect the time-flow to cause 3 completely separate events to happen all at once, and several hundred years apart?

Related: [How long do Dark Eldar live for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47477/how-long-do-dark-eldar-live-for)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The things the Warp does come in roughly two types:

1. Spew forth endless legions of Daemons to subjugate the Materium, kill every living creature and fashion their souls into underpants.
2. Whatever it wants. The Warp works in non-euclidian time and space ways potent and bizarre enough to kill a Doctor Who writer at 100 paces. The Warp does not care, the Warp just does. The story that you describe can be easily hand waved by telling your players (or at least suggesting) that the Warp did it, and they won't question it. For there lies madness and insanity in that direction. The Warp is an ill-defined place: use it like that.

Comment: The Warp is the domain of Chaos, and it is named aptly so. The events I outlined are well within the powers of the warp basically?

Comment: The Warp can do anything. One moment it can disperse strawberry jam while the next it launches puppy-shaped daemons at you who promptly proceed to eat your face, and yet the next de-ages you to half your age except that your liver becomes ten times as old. It's the Warp. It's a Thing that does Plot. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Just wanted to be clear that the warp is everything that is unclear... Haha